# Parse XML into object when all within one tag

Tags: xml, file, powershell, oop, parsing

The XML for a custom application is poorly configured, so all the data I want is between one tag, like so:

```
<PersonArray>
    <PersonInfo PersonName="" FavoriteFood="Ice Cream" 
             Username="friendlyperson" Location="Detroit"/>
</PersonArray>
```

It is an array, so multiple of these Persons will be added within the `<PersonArray>` tag in the same way. If I want to store every Person into an object, with each property being one of these headers (PersonName, FavoriteFood, etc.), how can I most effectively transition this poor XML into objects?

Comment: I'd recommend creating a POJO class called Person array that has a List<Person> people, where Person is also a POJO. You can use JAXB bindings to unmarshal the XML into your object.

Comment: @Ishnark I really didn't understand a word you just said

Comment: What do you mean by "poorly configured"? What does your input data look like, and what would you want your output data to look like? Have you tried anything yourself yet? What didn't work as expected?

Comment: Sorry, i realize that must have sounded like nonsense. Based on the other answers it seems like I misunderstood the question. The method I had in mind would involve you creating two classes in Java and then using an annotations to mark the fields of said classes to the appropriate XML tag, and then you could use an Unmarshaller to convert the XML to the Java Object. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I have a script to turn tags that open and close for each attribute into object properties, as in `<Name>Denise</Name><FavoriteFood>Ice Cream</FavoriteFood>`. But I don't know how to parse into something like this XML.

Comment: That doesn't answer any of my questions.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers The algorithm I have deals with data that looks like the comment I posted. It makes each tag a member of the object, and the `InnerText` attribute that member's value. That algorithm, when applied to the XML in my post, places the entire `<PersonInfo....../>` tag into one variable. This is not what I want. The difference is that there are not lcosing tags around `<PersonInfo>` and `<FavoriteFood>`, but rather they are all in one large tag.

Comment: *\*sigh\** Last try. The XML snippet in your question, is it your input? Your desired output? Your actual output?

Comment: That is the input to my script. My output would be an object containing each field listed as a member property.

Comment: Please [edit] your quesiton and **show** the desired output. Also **show** the code you currently have as well as the output that code generates from your input.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134016/discussion-between-alwaysquestioning-and-ansgar-wiechers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Esperento57's elegant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41821897/45375) shows how to **extract the `<PersonInfo>` elements as `[System.Xml.XmlElement]` instances.**
(A small caveat is that the `.SelectNodes()` method is not available in PowerShell *Core*, the cross-platform edition of PowerShell).

That may be all that is needed, given that these instances have properties reflecting the XML attributes (such as `PersonName`, `Location`, ...)

**If, by contrast, you want *custom objects* - plain objects restricted to `NoteProperty` members reflecting the XML attributes - more work is needed**:

```
# Sample input XML.
$xml = @'
<PersonArray>
    <PersonInfo PersonName="P1" FavoriteFood="Ice Cream" 
             Username="friendlyperson1" Location="Detroit" />
    <PersonInfo PersonName="P2" FavoriteFood="Cabbage" 
             Username="friendlyperson2" Location="Buffalo" />
</PersonArray>
'@

# Load the XML string into an XML document.
[xml] $doc = $xml

# Loop over the child nodes and turn each child element into a custom object
# based on its attributes.
$objs = $doc.ChildNodes | ForEach-Object {
  # Get the names of the `Property`-type members, which correspond
  # to the XML attributes.
  $propNames = ($_.ChildNodes | Get-Member -MemberType Property).Name
  # Create a custom object that only contains properties reflecting
  # the XML attribute.
  $_.ChildNodes | Select-Object -Property $propNames
}

# Output the resulting custom objects.
$objs
```

Answer (score 2):

try Something like this

```
[xml] $xml=gc "C:\temp\test.xml" 
$xml.SelectNodes("PersonArray/PersonInfo")
```

Comment: Kudos for elegance, but note that this outputs `[System.Xml.XmlElement]` instances, not custom objects containing only the values of interest (though maybe using the `[System.Xml.XmlElement]` instances directly is all the OP needs).
A small caveat is that the `.SelectNodes()` method is not available in PowerShell Core (the cross-platform edition).